# Yom Kippur Ashkenazi Selichos

Tags: yom-kippur, selichot

Does anyone know where I can find online or printed Yom Kippur Ashkenazi slichos for Shachrit Mincha and Musaf during chazarot hashatz?

Comment: This should have them https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/en/other-publications/90-machzor-yom-kippur If you can't get your hands on it or the like in time, note the specific Piyutim to use are not meakeiv and would have changed over time. Just pick something nice from the back of the Machzor or Slichot booklets and say a few with the 13 Middot. Best to pick in advance and provide sufficient printed copies for the whole congregation. Yishar Koach! The Jewish people need more organizers like you who go the extra mile serving their communities for the important traditions!

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Standard-Machsor-Day-Atonement-Hardcover-1925/dp/B000U1NI9E has it. You might find a whole bunch of these in a box in a closet at an old shul.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=yVAkD_XKZfMC&lpg=RA3-PA429&ots=jQfTnsmKAU&dq=%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA&pg=RA3-PA411#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=kdo8AAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA572&ots=MkkriKVNS5&dq=%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA&pg=PA561#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=EMlLAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PP235&ots=Xpmoxxq2-o&dq=%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA&pg=PP229#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=HJc9AAAAcAAJ&lpg=PT83&ots=qTKsm4plR6&dq=%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA&pg=PT283#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=iDA9AAAAcAAJ&lpg=PP604&ots=YRemt0DzDX&dq=%22%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA%22&pg=PP553#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=6jAQAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PP471&ots=u1Y_6ErQWl&dq=%22%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%AA%22&pg=PP436#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45016&st=&pgnum=159

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42206&st=&pgnum=72

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42658&st=&pgnum=57